# How to make nested submenus in ngx-contextmenu based on given object?

Tags: javascript, angular, components, contextmenu

I have an object nested structure of folders:

```
{
   "tree":[
      {
         "slug":"any",
         "title":"any",
         "children":[
            {
               "slug":"fff",
               "title":"fff",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "slug":"ppp",
                     "title":"ppp",
                     "children": []
                  },
                  {
                     "slug":"then",
                     "title":"then",
                     "children": []
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
         ],
         "expanded":true
      },
   ]
}
```

Each item with a `children` property is a folder. It should be presented this way:
[image]

I use the [ngx-contexmenu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-contextmenu) in the project. However, the problem with generating the the nested context menus (as each of the level is a separate context menu using this library) as in the example above is that this library uses template reference to add submenu of a context menu item. For example:

```
<ng-template contextMenuItem [subMenu]="saySubMenu">
  Say...
</ng-template>
<context-menu #saySubMenu>
  <ng-template contextMenuItem (execute)="showMessage('Hi, ' + $event.item.name)">
    ...hi!
  </ng-template>
</context-menu>
```

As I need a reference name for each submenu (`#saySubMenu`) it is very difficult to generate the submenus kind of dynamically like from the given object. I tried to create each submenu by resolveComponentFactory and set the reference name dynamically but I guess it may be impossible. Does anybody know how may I approach this problem?

Comment: you can add <ul> <li> tag for showing this kind of object inside your  <ng-template> tag and apply css as you want

Comment: @SnehaPawar how to generate a context menu then? Do you suggest to resign of using the library for the submenus?

Comment: i tried to do in the same object but unable to create multiple context-menu. checkout this if this is helpful to you https://plugins.codershood.info/#/plugins/ngmm-plugin